# Procedure only updates the first value

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, foreach, parameters

I have this SQL procedure for updating records given a **@StepId** value.
I got the values from a hidden field as an array and I loop them.
The problem is that the procedure only updates the first value.
The loop happen but do not update more than 1 value.
my array contains something like **{1000,2000,3000,}**
my parameters are 
**@StepId (int)
@DateCalculationRule (char)
@Result (int)**

```
Private Sub buttonCalculateDatesClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttonCalculateDates.Click

        Dim mySteps As String
        Dim myRule As String
        Dim ok As Integer = 1
        Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnnstring").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SaveStepDeadlineRule", conn)
        conn.Open()
        conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        myRule = HiddRule.Value
        mySteps = HiddStepIDs.Value

        'Separate string by comas
        Dim parts As String() = mySteps.Split(New Char() {","c})
        Dim part As String

        For Each part In parts

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StepId", part))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DateCalculationRule", myRule))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Result", 0))
            cmd.Parameters("@Result").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            Try

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ok = IIf(IsDBNull(cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value), 1, cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value)
                RadGrid1.Rebind()


            Catch ex As Exception
                ok = 1
            End Try

        Next
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Should you be clearing the parameters collection after each execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to clear down your parameters each time you loop:

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear
```

This is how it would be used:

```
For Each part In parts
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StepId", part))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DateCalculationRule", myRule))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Result", 0))
    cmd.Parameters("@Result").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    Try

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ok = IIf(IsDBNull(cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value), 1, cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value)
        RadGrid1.Rebind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ok = 1
    End Try

Next
```

You could create the parameters outside the loop since they don't change and then just assign the value each time you loop:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StepId", 0))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DateCalculationRule", ""))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Result", 0))
cmd.Parameters("@Result").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

For Each part In parts
    cmd.Parameters("@StepId").Value = part
    cmd.Parameters("@DateCalculationRule").Value = myRule

    Try

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ok = IIf(IsDBNull(cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value), 1, cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value)
        RadGrid1.Rebind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ok = 1
    End Try

Next
```